# iCloud, Dropbox and others

Tags: storage

First, when I click on the dropbox, nothing happens.  I get no files or anything.  How do I access what's in the dropbox?  Mine is full.
Next, I am fed up with limited storage on iCloud, Dropbox and the like.  I want to get rid of these as I will not pay the money to upgrade.  How do I get rid of them and sync directly to my iMac from my iPad and iPhone???

Answer (score 2):

> I am fed up with limited storage
>
> I will not pay the money to upgrade

That's the problem right there.

Comment: You got it.  I think I was able to moveal files and UNlink the dropbox.  Time will tell.  Next to attack iCloud!!!

Answer (score 0):

Both Dropbox and iCloud work in very similar manners.

You can turn off syncing at any time and then copy the files from the "chosen" folder for each sync option to save them anywhere on your filesystem.

You don't have to turn things off to prune the storage and ride the "free" tier. Don't pay for something if you don't need extra storage - but those options are there for little money on iCloud side to get you over a temporary spike in storage needs if you need a month to clear things out.

Apple bundles a mostly integrated personal cloud storage solution with Server.app - which costs money and is generally much more time to learn how to operate than the time it takes to learn how to maintain files on dropbox or iCloud in terms of initial setup.

However, once you set up your server, there is no bill for exceeding the storage space on the server hard drive - and that included attaching as many external drives as you care. Server can run on any Mac that runs the normal OS and you don't have to leave it running all the time, but of course files won't sync when it's not running and connected to the network.